# Laravel Polymorph many to many with pivot

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I'm trying to do relationship between my `shops` table and `parts`, `items`, `ASICs` tables.
I have the following tables:

- shops (id, name, ...)
- shopables (id, shop_id, shopable_type, shopable_id, price, count, ...).
  P.S. Maybe, by the way, I should rename it to good_shop (good_type, good_id)?
- parts (id, name, ...)
- items (id, name, ...)
- ASICs (id, name, ...)

And a little notice: Instead of 'App\Part' I save to shopable_type `part` (`item`, `ASIC`).

So, I need to have the following methods in my models:

- Part, Item, ASIC - `shops()`
- Shop - `goods()`

How can I do that? I was trying but there's always something wrong, I can't connect this tables to each other :(

```js
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\traits\HasImage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

class Shop extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use HasImage;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'type', 'slug', 'delivery_time', 'warranty'];

//    public function parts()
//    {
//        return $this
//            ->belongsToMany(Part::class)
//            ->using(GoodShopPivot::class)
//            ->withPivot('id', 'count');
//    }
//
//    public function items()
//    {
//        return $this
//            ->belongsToMany(Item::class)
//            ->using(GoodShopPivot::class)
//            ->withPivot('id', 'count', 'price', 'currency');
//    }


    public function shopables()
    {
        Relation::morphMap([
            'part' => 'App\Part',
            'item' => 'App\Item',
            'asic' => 'App\ASIC',
        ]);

        return $this->morphTo('shopable');
    }
}
```

```js
<?php

namespace App\Models;

class Part extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     */
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'GPU_real_hashrate', 'real_temperature', 'PSU_breaks_chance'];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

//    public function shops()
//    {
//        return $this
//            ->belongsToMany(Shop::class)
//            ->withPivot(['count', 'price'])
//            ->using(GoodShopPivot::class);
//    }
//
    public function shops()
    {
//        return $this->morphToMany('App\Shop', 'shopable')->withPivot('price', 'count', 'currency');

        return $this
            ->morphTo(Shop::class, 'shopable')
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are pretty much on point some things need to be handled a bit differently in this approach. I will try addressing it in my answer.

Comment: i think this video will help you to understand more about laravel polymorphic relationships
https://youtu.be/KfwCvUQz-rc

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using polymorphic relationships to create associations between your `Shop` model and other models (`Part`, `Item`, `ASICs`). To achieve the methods you want, you need to adjust your relationships in the models.

First, let's focus on the `Shop` model. I suggest renaming the `shopables` table to `good_shop` to make it more descriptive, as you mentioned. Also, ensure that the polymorphic relationships are set up correctly. Here's how you can modify your models:

### Shop Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

class Shop extends Model
{
    public function goods(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Good::class, 'goodable')
            ->withPivot('price', 'count');
    }
}
```

Now, create a Good model that will be the base for your polymorphic relationships:

### Good Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;

class Good extends Model
{
    public function shops(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Shop::class, 'goodable')
            ->withPivot('price', 'count');
    }
}
```

This is where you will need to take a different approach than Laravel's convention. Now Finally, update your `Part`, `Item`, and `ASICs` models to extend the `Good` model:

### Part Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Part extends Good
{
    // Additional Part-specific attributes and methods
}
```

*repeat the same for `Item` and `ASICs` Models, to form a Polymorphic relation*

Now, with the above adjustments your desired models should work as expected:

### Example

```
$shop = Shop::find($shopId);
$goods = $shop->goods; // Returns a collection of Part, Item, and ASIC models
```

This is how your `good_shop` migration should look like:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('good_shop', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('goodable'); // Adds goodable_id and goodable_type
        $table->decimal('price', 8, 2);
        $table->integer('count');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('good_shop');
}
```

Comment: I apreciate your help, but I get error: `Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.goods' doesn't exist`. And I can't figure out how to make laravel user goodable_type.
By the way, why did you name it goodable instaed of shopable?

Comment: This query that laravel generates causes error:
`select
  `goods`.*,
  `goodables`.`goodable_id` as `pivot_goodable_id`,
  `goodables`.`good_id` as `pivot_good_id`,
  `goodables`.`goodable_type` as `pivot_goodable_type`,
  `goodables`.`price` as `pivot_price`,
  `goodables`.`count` as `pivot_count`
from
  `goods`
  inner join `goodables` on `goods`.`id` = `goodables`.`good_id`
where
  `goodables`.`goodable_id` in (1, 2, 3, 5, 14, 15)
  and `goodables`.`goodable_type` = App \ Models \ Shop`

Comment: you need to creata a `goods` table for `Good::class` to work or else you can specify the `protected $table = 'your_table_name'` in your `Good` Model to tell it to use that table whenever queried.

Comment: but... There are 3types of goods: part, item, ASIC. For each type I have a table in database: parts, items, ASICs. I don't need goods table.
I want to create one methods for Shop with relationship that returns all related parts, items and ASICs at the same time.
And also I need methods for getting shops from Part, Item and ASIC models. 
Is it even possible to do in laravel? I think that it's better to make 3 relationships and 1 accessor "goods" that collect this 3 relationships together

Comment: Is it even possible in Laravel? Yes, it is.

**"I think that it's better to make 3 relationships and 1 accessor "goods" that collect this 3 relationships together"** this is exactly what is happening in the above solution. I made a mistake in my earlier comment. You are not supposed to use `Good::class` directly. if you do `Shop::find($id)->goods()` you will get good from that shop. Similarly if you do `Item::find($id)->shops()` you will get all shops where that item exists, since `Item`, `Part` and `ASIC` are aggregated from `Good` they all have `shops()` method available.

Comment: so how do I need to change Shop model to fix this behaviour?
If I type `return $this->morphToMany(Good::class, 'good', 'good_shop')` - i get error that `goods` table doesn't exist. And when I don't user 3rd arg `good_shop``, I get error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'goods'`.

Comment: Here's the generated query:
`select `goods`.*, `goods`.`good_id` as `pivot_good_id`, `goods`.`good_type` as `pivot_good_type`, `goods`.`price` as `pivot_price`, `goods`.`count` as `pivot_count` from `goods` inner join `goods` on `goods`.`id` = `goods`.`good_id` where `goods`.`good_id` = 1 and `goods`.`good_type` = App\Models\Shop`

Comment: so, can you guess what's the matter?

Comment: As I can see, there's no way to do it using only one relationship:(
Here's example https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/polymorphic-many-to-many-relation-to-multiple-models